# Nudging an array from it's zero item

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array encoded in UTF-8, sorta like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => אלף
[1] => בית
[2] => גימל
[3] => דלת
[4] => הא
[5] => ואו
)
```

Is it possible to leave the 0 array item empty and start the array at 1? I sorta wanna nudge everything over, and the array would then look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => אלף
[2] => בית
[3] => גימל
[4] => דלת
[5] => הא
[6] => ואו
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *empty*? A zero-length string?

Comment: Yeah, a zero length string.

Comment: Then doesn't @Dave Chen's answer work for you? I mean it should do what you're asking for, I'd say as well for your concrete case `array_unshift` looks like the right tool.

Comment: Thanks! It does work for me. But now that I'm dumping out other arrays it seems that really I needed to move the array in the reverse order (meaning that the 0 item is already empty, and I need to shift everything downward to fill the 0 item.

Comment: I suggest to take a little read on the PHP manual and all it's glory array functions. It's a full tool-set so get a bit into it: http://php.net/arrays / http://php.net/ref.array

Answer (score 5):

Use [`array_unshift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php), example:

```
<?php

$arr=array(1,2,3);
array_unshift($arr,null);

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Prints `Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 )`